# Logging a nodejs application into DigitalOcean Spaces using Winston

Tags: node.js, logging, digital-ocean, winston

Does Winston support a writable stream object that uploads to DigitalOcean Spaces?

There is for example [s3-streamlogger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-streamlogger) for S3 objects, but I could not find a direct way to use winston with spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Spaces Documentation](https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/spaces/#aws-s3-compatibility), Spaces is compatible with AWS S3 API:

> The Spaces API aims to be interoperable with Amazon's AWS S3 API. In
>   most cases, when using a client library, setting the "endpoint" or
>   "base" URL to ${REGION}.digitaloceanspaces.com and generating a Spaces
>   key to replace your AWS IAM key will allow you to use Spaces in place
>   of S3.

So I ended up using [s3-streamlogger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-streamlogger) with `Winston` to upload logs into my spaces bucket:

```
import   winston          from 'winston';
import { S3StreamLogger } from 's3-streamlogger';

const s3Stream = new S3StreamLogger({
  bucket: "mybucket",
  config: {
    endpoint: 'nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com',
  },
  access_key_id: "MY_ACCESS_KEY",
  secret_access_key: "MY_SECRET_KEY",
  tags: {type: "mytype", project: "myproject"}
});

const s3Transport = new winston.transports.Stream({
  stream: s3Stream
});

export const logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [s3Transport]
});

logger.info('Hello Winston!');
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I'm getting an error "InvalidArgument" when it tries to upload the log.  Did you run into this?